# Load a .ttf font file as binary data outside the assets folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a .ttf font file and I want to load it as binary data. I know I can load binary data as TextAsset in Unity. But this requires the file extensions to be ".fnt" or ".bytes" (few more extensions I know). If I change the file extension, I am able to load the file as binary data in TextAsset. But I don't want to change the file type.

Is there a method in Unity where I can load the .ttf file as binary data without changing the file

Is there a way I can load the .ttf file as Font Asset in Unity and then get the raw font data from the Font Asset?

Or some other way of loading the .ttf font as binary data?

Comment: [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-6.0) or other System.IO functions available in .Net framework.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. I doubt you want answers in this language